# How to plot perpendicular bisector of a line in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to make a minimum distance classifier and I need to draw a perpendicular bisector of a line to plot the decision boundary. I have a point and even the slope of the bisector. How can I draw it on the graph?

Answer (score 0):

The following function will draw a line given the center point and the slope:

```
function drawLine(point,slope)
% point - vector [x,y]
% slope - slope of the line

x = point(1);
y = point(2);

lengthLine = 5;

xLine = x-lengthLine:x+lengthLine;
yLine = slope*(xLine-x) + y;

plot(x,y,'ro')
plot(xLine,yLine,'b')
```